# Disable HSQLDB Server logs within console

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

Hey everybody this is my first post so I apologize if I leave off any needed information. I have a Java program that is setup to use Hibernate with a HSQL database. I was able to get Hibernate logs limited in my console however I cannot find anyway to suppress the HSQL Server logs that appear. Any ideas?

Example log:

```
[Server@53d8d10a]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
[Server@53d8d10a]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited
[Server@53d8d10a]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: setDatabasePath(0,file:realitystocks)
[Server@53d8d10a]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
[Server@53d8d10a]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited
[Server@53d8d10a]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: setDatabaseName(0,stocks
[Server@53d8d10a]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: start() entered
[Server@53d8d10a]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @53d8d10a,5,main]]: run() entered
[Server@53d8d10a]: Initiating startup sequence...
```

The way I was able to limit Hibernate logs was using the following:

```
Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
```

However this same solution did not work for HSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start the server, use `server.silent=true` in the properties or the equivalent on the command line.

Comment: You're a life saver!! Based on your answer I was able to find/use server.setSilent(true); This does not completely suppress all Server logs however it significantly reduces the displayed messages to the console. What remains is mainly the startup sequences but the log is readable now without having to scroll through a huge log. Thank you!!!

Comment: Any idea how to do this using `Java Opts`?

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody else has this same issue, doing a

```
server.setLogWriter(null);
```

made the server absolutely silent.